How to Enable FS-Cache for CephFS in Kubernetes Containers Using Ceph-CSI?
I'm using Kubernetes with Ceph-CSI to mount CephFS volumes in pods. I want to enable FS-Cache so that files read from CephFS are cached locally on the node for faster access.
I've installed cachefilesd on the host and enabled caching with the -o fsc option when mounting CephFS directly on the host. The cache is created under /var/cache/fscache/, but when checking the mounts in the pods, I don't see the fsc option enabled.
How can I enable FS-Cache for CephFS mounts in Kubernetes pods using Ceph-CSI?

If you want to enable FS-Cache for CephsFS in kubernetes pods and if you have already installed the cachefilesd make sure that the cachefilesd service is running on all the kubernetes nodes. And you can enable and start the cachefilesd service on your nodes using the following commands, and also you can refer to this document for more information.
sudo systemctl enable cachefilesd
Sudo systemctl start cachefilesd

Also make sure that the ceph-csi driver supports the required mount options (FSI). You can specify the mount options  as part of the CephFS provisioner or in the storage class configuration.
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
Kind: storageClass
metadata:
   Name: cephs-storage
provisioner:kuberenetes.io/rbd
parameters:
   monitors: <ceph-monitors>
   pool: cephsfs_data
   fsType: ceph
controller-publish-secret-namespace:
default
  mountOptions: “fsc”

Note : Ensure that the nodes have sufficient disk space and permissions to store the cache under / var / cache / fscache.

I have mounted CephFS in my pod with the fsc option enabled. However, I noticed that the cache directory on the host machine (/var/cache/fscache) isn't increasing as expected after performing read operations within the pod (e.g., cat /mnt/data/testfile > /dev/null). Does cachefilesd service need to be installed inside the pod。

No the Cachesfield service does not need to be installed inside the pod. The cachesfield service and FS-Cache functionality are managed at host level not inside the pod.Ensure the cachesfield is running on the node and correctly configured to use /var/cache/fscache.

Thank you very much for your response! After restarting the pod and performing the read operation again, the caching functionality is now working as expected.
